# Manipulate multiple buckets in gsutil via regex or wildcard at once

Tags: cors, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I need to manipulate these buckets, to set CORS configurations:

```
gs://prefix-<40 char hex hash>
```

But not these buckets

```
gs://prefix-<anything else>
```

The regex `gs://prefix-\{\w\\}40` will do.

I can manipulate multiple buckets via wildcard but it looks like I need something stronger than a wildcard.

I haven't been able to find in depth documentation on what gsutil accepts yet.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard support includes `?`. So

```
gs://prefix-????????????????????????????????????????
```

will probably do it.